# Granting DBA privileges to user in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How do I grant a user DBA rights in Oracle? I guess something like:

```
CREATE USER NewDBA
IDENTIFIED BY passwd;

GRANT DBA TO NewDBA WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Is it the right way, or...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You need only to write:

`GRANT DBA TO NewDBA;`

Because this already makes the user a DB Administrator